# Azure devops deployment

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment

Failed to deploy web package to IIS website. 
Error: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Create File' on `D:\Websites\project\project.pdb`.

> Error: The error code was 0x800704C8. Error: The requested operation
>   cannot be performed on a file with a user- mapped section open.

I have tried to add this 
`MSDEPLOY_RENAME_LOCKED_FILES = 1` on variables

Comment: Have you checked Resource Monitor to see if another application is locking that file?

Comment: Yes i did checked if there is no application locking the file

Comment: Have you tried checking permissions on the folder?

Comment: I had to restart the server, i'm now able to deploy. thank you m00nbeam360.0